# All website links broken when behind NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have a website, w1, on server A and on server B I have an NGINX installation.

From my development machine C I can navigate to b.uk/w1 and can see my home page, physically located on A. However, when I click a link to go to page p1 the link doesn't have my application part, w1, in the url.

I expect b.uk/w1/p1

I get b.uk/p1

Is this an NGINX thing? or do I need to rewrite my application so all links (including .js and .css) have /w1 prepended to them? This seems ugly. What if Its w2 somewhere else? do I need to version by server application therefore?

Is there a way I can get the website to treat /w1 as part of the domain? I guess this depends on what I used to build it?

Maybe there is an nginx setting I am missing. currently my location block is very simple:

```
location /w1/ {
  proxy_pass http://A/;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Post your nginx.conf and virtual server configuration file, where the root directory of your server located? and where all the js and css located?.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to achieve this. the work around was as follows:
https://www.billbogaiv.com/posts/net-core-hosted-on-subdirectories-in-nginx
Of course, this was the solution for me, given that the application I was writing was done so using asp .net core. It'll most certainly be different for other scenarios. The general idea is this;

asp .net core has some functionality to prepend to the relative links it generates, for hrefs in a and link(css) tags, src in img and script tags etc the location part of your url from your nginx configs location block, as you specify it in some config (either application.json or hardcoded in your app start logic).

If your framework of choice doesn't support this natively you'll to build this in.